# Math problem I’m struggling with writing down my reasoning for

Tags: contest-math

The question is as such:
At least how many stars should be drawn in a $4\times4$ table such that after eliminating two arbitrary columns and two arbitrary rows at least one star will remain in the table

I know the answer is $7$ stars but i don’t know how to write down my reasoning.

I just need a place to start and any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Are you saying that you were able to prove that the answer is $7$ by reasoning but you are unable to type that reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

To prove that something is the least value subject to some constraint, first prove that **it indeed satisfies the constraint** (in your case, show that after eliminating two arbitrary columns and two arbitrary rows at least one star will remain in the table if 7 stars are drawn); then prove that **any smaller value does not** (in your case, show that after eliminating two arbitrary columns and two arbitrary rows it is possible that no stars remain in the table if less than 7 stars are drawn). Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have $4$ stars, then putting the stars on a diagonal is an optimal solution (however, any composition such that the rank of a $4\times 4$ matrix is full would work). That is,
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
* & & & \\
& * & & \\
& & * & \\
& & & *
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Now, if rows $R$ and columns $C$ are chosen and $R\cap C\neq \emptyset$, then there would be one star left in the matrix. For example, removing rows $1$ & $2$ and columns $2$ & $3$ would leave the star at $(4,4)$ location. However, if $R\cap C = \emptyset$, then all starts will be removed. For example, removing rows $1$ & $2$ and columns $3$ & $4$ would remove all the stars.

Suppose you remove rows $1$ & $2$, then you must have at least one star in the locations $(3,1)$, $(3,2)$, $(4,1)$, and $(4,2)$. In such a case, one can change a strategy and instead choose columns $1$ & $2$, then there must be at least one star in the location $(1,3)$, $(1,4)$, $(2,3)$, and $(2,4)$.

It can be generalized to the following: When two rows $i$ & $j$ are chosen, there should be a star in the location $(k,i)$, $(k,j)$, $(l,i)$, and $(l,j)$. When two columns $i$ & $j$ are chosen, there should be a star in the location $(i,k)$, $(i,l)$, $(j,k)$, and $(j,l)$. Since any two rows or any two columns can be chosen, we must have two extra stars to 'dodge' the row and column choices. This gives $4$ stars chosen in the beginning, $2$ additional stars, and $2$ extra 'dodgers'. So the minimum number of required stars is $8$, not $7$.

For instance, the following is a solution
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
* & & * & * \\
& * & &  \\
* & & * & \\
* & & & *
\end{array}\right]
$$

Comment: What about? $$
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
* & & & \\
& * &* & \\
& & * &* \\
& *& & *
\end{array}
\right]
$$